# python filename=None

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. I heard that when we initialize a function we should always start by self but I didn't get the `fileName=None`. What does this argument stand for?

```
def __init__(self, fileName=None):
```

Comment: The stuff with `self` only applies to methods in a class, not to standalone functions. For the beginning, it is better not to mix up these 2 things.

Comment: Mona, this is basic programming stuff. To start, you should first take the time to follow/read any of the available python book/tutorials. Dont rely on everything you hear :-)

Answer (score 2):

It is a default value for the parameter `fileName`. If the caller does not specify a value, it will be set to `None`. This code demonstrates it:

```
def foo(bar=None):
    print bar

foo() # will print the default value
>> None
foo(1) # will print the given value
>> 1
```

Note that default parameter values in Python are tricky, because the expression will be [evaluated exactly once, when the function definition is executed](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions).

Comment: @mona: It is not. If you have further question, ask them here. Before doing so, read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) carefully. Also, before asking other basic Python questions, read the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/).